# Dynamically create a JSON object in JavaScript and return it

Tags: javascript, json

I have a function, that should return a JSON, like this:

```
this.test = (x, filename) => {
  if (x.isPresent()) {
    return {
      'result': true
    };
  } else
    return {
      'result': false 'value': x + "is missing in file" + filename
    };
}
```

and I have a function, that calls this:

```
returnedResult = test("saveButton", "AdminPage")
console.log(returnedResult)
console.log(returnedResult.result)
```

Both `returnedResult` and `returnedResult.result` are always getting printed as `undefined`. How should I return as a correct JSON?

Comment: You're missing an opening bracket in your else statement and some JSON commas, other than that things look right. Can you adapt your question to this simple example? This works if you look in the console: http://jsfiddle.net/f91vujdr/3/.

Comment: Clear the code in your question isn't actually the code you have. You've created a few syntax errors in the process of copying it here.

Comment: I posted an answer, though the syntax error can also assumed to be a simple typographical error, and if, let me know and I'll delete my answer and "Vote to close" as such

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a bracket `}` on this line `} else`, and a comma `,` in your return value on line `'result': false`), so here is a working sample

*Note, I temporarily altered the `isPresent` function for it to work in this sample*

```js
function isPresent(x) { return true; }

test = (x, filename) => {
  if (isPresent(x)) {
    return {
      'result': true
    };
  } else {
    return {
      'result': false,
      'value': x + "is missing in file" + filename
    };
  }
}


returnedResult = test("saveButton", "AdminPage")
console.log(returnedResult)
console.log(returnedResult.result)
```